# Run VBA for each record in a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

Given a form which continuously displays certain text boxes for a each record of a table, I'd like a VBA sub to be executed after all text boxes for each record have been (automatically, not via VBA) populated with data from the current record. So the idealized order of execution would be:

```
fetch next record from table
distribute values into text boxes and draw
execute VBA
fetch next record from table
```

How can I achieve this?

**Note:** The form is "continuous" (I don't know how to say this in access-jargon), i. e. displays all records at once, and not one record at a time with buttons for moving forward/backward.

**Note 2:** What I achieve to do is the following: I have a table `F` that contains names of fields of another table `T`. My form iterates through the rows of `F`. For each field name listed in `F`, I want to print out the name, and build a query that draws a histogram showing the data from `T` for that column.

Comment: Not clear enough what do you mean "distribute values into text boxes". Manually fill values? In any case you can add a calculated column to base query, which calls VBA function with parameters from fields for text boxes, it will be recalled for each field after changing the data in text boxes.

Comment: That's bad database design. Field names are not for storing data. If you have a table with field names for fields in another table, that's a clear indication your data is not normalized and your design needs to be adjusted. If you don't adjust your database design, you can't achieve what you intend to. Similar data should be stored in the same field, with another field to differentiate the type of data, instead of separate fields.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: Some configurable databases have tables of tables and fields, it is a powerful data management tool in a complex information environment. Also not for the faint-hearted!

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth The database design is debatable indeed, but out of my influence. However, I doubt that a properly normalized database would solve the problem: Given a table with an additional column `attribute`, you would still have to iterate over all distinct values for `attribute` and populate the histograms accordingly.

Comment: @Bubaya You don't have to iterate through it, then. You can just use a chart with a record source that includes all data for all records, and use the _link master field_ and _link child field_ property to get the right data with the right record.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: I wasn't aware of these two properties. Without them, I couldn't imagine how to do this without iteration. But I think it can be done also with this bad database design without iteration then.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: I've tried to follow your advice to normalize the database. However, this won't help me since access complains about the queries' complexity by now. Please consider having a look at my [follow up-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49317534).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. In continuous forms in Access, controls have only a single instance. Any operation on a control influences that control for all records.

There are no separate events per record on a continuous form.

You can iterate through the records, but only before or after the form has been populated.

Comment: That is bad news for me. Please se my edit for what I am trying to do. Viewing one record at a time is fine on screen; however, when I want to print, I always end up with the continous view, with my histograms not updated between two records.