# Follow up: Access considers query too complex after normalization

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-normalization

At first, I want to apologize for the *n*+1st Query-too-complex-question.

Since [I've been told that my dtabase deserves normalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49275559/), I tried to do the very same thing with a normalised setup. However, Access complains about a too complex query by now.

**What I want to do:** Starting point is a query that yields fields `Item ID, Difference in attribute 1, Group of attribute 1, Difference in Attribute 2, Group of attribute 2,...` (about 10.000 rows, query is just an equijoin of the two datasets to compare). For each attribute, I want to draw a histogram showing the distribution of differences for that attribute. In fact, I want to draw two histograms in one canvas, one of which is constrained to Group = 1.

**What I tried:**

- First step was to build a normalisation query (based on `union`s) which yields columns `Item ID, attribute, difference, group`. This query yields about 100.000 rows.
- Next step is to draw the histogram. Unfortunately, access has no built-in histogram chart, so I resorted to a xy-chart whose data source is a query that is a union of four queries that yield the for corners of the bins.
- Since I want to draw two histograms, this data source query is `union`ed with a copy of itself that bears the additional `group = 1`-condition.

So I endet up with the following query:

```
select bin, max(c), max(c2) from (
    -- collect the four corners of the first histogram
    select bin, cnt as c, 1 as c2, ord from (
        -- top right
        select
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) + 0.05) AS bin,
            Count(bin) AS cnt,
            1 as ord
        FROM normalized_data
        WHERE difference Is Not Null
            and attribut='attibute_name'
            and difference between -2 and 2
        GROUP BY
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) + 0.05)

        union all

        -- bottom right
        select
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) + 0.05) AS bin,
            0 AS cnt,
            2 as ord
        FROM normalized_data
        WHERE difference Is Not Null
            and attribut='attibute_name'
            and difference between -2 and 2
        GROUP BY
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) + 0.05)

        union all

        -- bottom left
        select
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) - 0.05) AS bin,
            0 AS cnt,
            3 as ord
        FROM normalized_data
        WHERE difference Is Not Null
            and attribut='attibute_name'
            and difference between -2 and 2
        GROUP BY
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) - 0.05)

        union all

        -- top left
        select
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) - 0.05) AS bin,
            Count(bin) AS cnt,
            4 as ord
        FROM normalized_data
        WHERE difference Is Not Null
            and attribut='attibute_name'
            and difference between -2 and 2
        GROUP BY
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) - 0.05)
        order by bin, ord asc
    ) 

    union all 

    -- connect the corners of the other one
    select bin, 1 as c, cnt as c2, ord from (
        select
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) + 0.05) AS bin,
            Count(bin) AS cnt,
            1 as ord
        FROM normalized_data
        WHERE difference Is Not Null
            and attribut='attibute_name'
            and difference between -2 and 2
            AND (GR=1)
        GROUP BY
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) + 0.05)
        union all
        select
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) + 0.05) AS bin,
            0 AS cnt,
            2 as ord
        FROM normalized_data
        WHERE difference Is Not Null
            and attribut='attibute_name'
            and difference between -2 and 2
            AND (GR=1)
        GROUP BY
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) + 0.05)
        union all
        select
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) - 0.05) AS bin,
            0 AS cnt,
            3 as ord
        FROM normalized_data
        WHERE difference Is Not Null
            and attribut='attibute_name'
            and difference between -2 and 2
            AND (GR=1)
        GROUP BY
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) - 0.05)
        union all
        select
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) - 0.05) AS bin,
            Count(bin) AS cnt,
            4 as ord
        FROM normalized_data
        WHERE difference Is Not Null
            and attribut='attibute_name'
            and difference between -2 and 2
            AND (GR=1)
        GROUP BY
            cdbl(bin(difference, 0.1, -2, 2) - 0.05)
        order by bin, ord asc
    )
) 
group by bin, ord 
order by bin, ord asc
```

The two innermost `union`s are computed, as well as the two queries in the middle level. However, when I try to compute the outermost `union`, access complains about the query's complexity (which did not happen on the unnormalized query)

**Question:** Do I have any chance to resolve this?

**Remark:** The middle step has been introduced to ease automatic code generation. Removal doesn't solve the problem.

**Edit: What is in the tables:** As requested, I shall add some information about what is stored in tables and what is queried. I am given two tables

```
create table A (
    id integer not null primary key,
    [attribute 1] integer,
    [attribute 2] integer,
    ...
)

create table B (
    id integer not null primary key,
    [attribute 1] integer,
    [attribute 2] integer,
    ...
)
```

and a query `differences` to complare them:

```
select
    id,
    A.[attribute 1] - B.[attribute 1] as [delta 1],
    ...
from A
inner join B on A.id = B.id
```

I am aware that this unnormalized data model is bad design, but I am not the person in charge to design the model. This is why a have built a query `normalized_data` which unpivots the data from `differences`:

```
select
    id,
    'attribute 1' as attribute,
    delta 1 as difference
from differences
union all
select
    id,
    'attribute 2' as attribute,
    delta 2 as difference
from differences
union all
...
```

Note that the code for the query in question above does not change very much if one uses the unnormalized data from `differences` as input, or the unpivoted data from `normalized_data`.

Comment: Try to save the "inner" union queries as separate queries. Then use these in the "outer" union query.

Comment: You can also try to perform the grouping in a separate query. Grouping union queries can cause trouble, especially if they're this complex.

Comment: Do you mean your "starting query" is the one giving normalized_data? That table is a poor design, relevant to display to humans but not further querying. Your code is complex because you are undoing (unpivoting) what should not have been done (pivoting). Please show the DDL for the "two datasets to compare" and what "query is just an equijoin of the two" that produced normalized_data. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please do not rely on links, put what is necessary for this question in this question.

Comment: @philipxy: it is certainly true that it is poor design to have pivoted data stored in the original table, but a matter which is out of my influence. However, the complexity of the query is not due to the unpivoting, but due to necessity to manually "draw" all boxes of a histogram into an xy plot. Nevertheless, I have added the missing information.

Comment: Thanks. [mcve] please we can cut & paste & run.